# Building a Relationship Between Attributes Or Columns Of Bits "Flatting it out"

Tags: sql, database-design

I have the following SQL design issue. The code below might look a little much but basically I have a table of cars and another table of attributes the car could have. This makes complete sense to me to structure a table of attributes for an object using a linking table, #CarSupportedAtttibutes.  Recently I've been tasked with doing something similar but use one table that has each of the Attributes as columns making it "flat".  Similar to below:

[CarId][Name][Manual Transmission][Sunroof][Automatic Transmission][AWD]

I am told doing so it will boost the speed of my queries, but its starting to turn into a nightmare.  In C# I have enumerated values for each of the car's attributes, 1 = Manual Transmission, so using the non "flat" version I am able to pull off a query pretty quickly as the SQL code below shows.  Since I am being pushed to making the table flat for speed the only way I can think of is to take the enumerated value and build it into the where clause, using a case statement for every 1,2,3 and selecting off a column name.

To me it just makes more sense to organize the data like below.  Like what if a new attribute about a car is needed, say "HEMI Engine".  Not all cars are going to have this, in fact its going to be a rare case.  But The way I am told to design is to keep the table "flat", so now I would be adding a Column called "Hemi Engine" to my table, instead of adding a row in my CarAttributes, and then only adding rows for the cars that have that as true.

Below is a snippet of the way I currently see approaching this problem, as opposed to doing a "flat" table (table with mostly columns of bits).

Question: What design makes more sense? Which is more maintainable? Am I completely crazy for thinking below is a better approach, and why?

```
CREATE TABLE #Car
(
    CarId INT,
    Name VARCHAR(250)
)

INSERT INTO #Car VALUES (1, 'Fusion')
INSERT INTO #Car VALUES (2, 'Focus')


CREATE TABLE #CarAttributes
(
    AttributeId INT,
    Name VARCHAR(250)
)

INSERT INTO #CarAttributes VALUES (1, 'Manual Transmission')
INSERT INTO #CarAttributes VALUES (2, 'SunRoof')


SELECT * FROM #CarAttributes

CREATE TABLE #CarSupportedAttributes
(
    AttributeId INT,
    CarId INT
)
INSERT INTO #CarSupportedAttributes VALUES (1,2)


--Determine if A Focus has a manual transmission
SELECT * FROM #Car c
INNER JOIN #CarSupportedAttributes csa
    ON csa.CarId = c.CarId
INNER JOIN #CarAttributes ca
    ON ca.AttributeId = csa.AttributeId 
WHERE c.Name = 'Focus'
    AND ca.AttributeId = 1
```

Comment: Your approach is sane. And your reasoning, too. With the other method, as you point, every new attribute will make you change the schema. That is not good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is known as Entity-Attribute-Value, or EAV (yours is slightly modified, since in your model the *presence* of the attribute on the entity is the value, but the concept is the same).

EAV is *usually* considered an anti-pattern, but it can be appropriate in some cases. Basically, if either...

- Your list of attributes is large and any given entity (car) will have only a small percentage of the total attributes
- Your list of attributes is subject to frequent user change and they represent only data and not anything structural about the entity

Then EAV can be an appropriate choice. I can't answer either of those questions for you (though I have my suspicions), but it does seem like it might be appropriate in your case.

The other option, which is likely what most 6NF proponents would suggest, would be to have a table per attribute, like `CarSunroof` or `CarManualTransmission`. This would solve the first issue and the requirement of changing a table's definition whenever a new attribute is added, but would not address the issue of the user being able to change it.

Comment: Lets say that the car was going to have only two columns till the end of time. [Manual][Automatic] How would you structure the query to see if a Focus has Attribute = 1  (1 is the enumerated value being passed in by c# to the proc) Without building CASE logic into the Where clause

Comment: @Adam: What if all these columsn are bit columns? Isn't this different?

Comment: Yes all the columns are going to be bits, only truth is being tested.

Comment: I don't disagree with you. I'm going to guess that the result set needs to be fed into a report writer, or something else that needs rows of named columns.  If that's the case, building rows from columns will be considerably slower than selecting columns from rows.  Building rows from columns for the 'n' attributes of a car (50?) will require 'n - 1' joins. (Or the equivalent of n - 1 joins in application or middle-tier code.)

Comment: The results are used from C# to either Query SQL to find out all cars that have AttributeId=2 or seeing if any one carId has AtrributeId=2. The real problem is the Attribute=2 means Airbags on C# so the WHERE CLAUSE gets tricky because I only know Attribute=2... So in the proc i need to build a case saying Case @ID =2 then [AirBags]

Comment: @cgatian: You're essentially talking about an abstraction, not how the data should be structured. There's not even any requirement that all of your "attributes" follow one particular methodology. For example, if you know that *every* car is going to have some form of transmission (and such information should be required), then you should make that a part of the `Car` table. Rather than thinking "this car has an attribute called manual transmission" or one called "automatic transmission", think "what kind of transmission does it have"?

Comment: This also solves the problem of being able to have both the manual and automatic transmission attributes present on a car. Then you go down the road of making some attributes related and exclusive, which results in yet MORE engineering.

Comment: @Adam Robinson: Completely agree.  Just some quick detail off the top of my head.